# Dealing with authenticated vs. authorized users with Flask-Login

Tags: python, authentication, flask, authorization, flask-login

I've managed to make a Flask-Login app that will log people in using LDAP.  That is, I can use the login process and @login_required decorators to distinguish between two types of users:

1. Unauthenticated (username/password not recognized as a valid combo in LDAP)
2. Authenticated (user can login to LDAP using the given username/password)

What I want now is:

1. Unauthenticated (username/password not recognized as a valid combo in LDAP)
2. Unauthorized (username/password is a valid LDAP combo, but user is not a member of the right LDAP groups)
3. Authorized (user's credentials are in LDAP and user is a member of the appropriate LDAP groups)

In pseudocode, I'd like this:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

# This is for any authenticated user
@app.route('/allmembers')
@login_required
def allmembers():
    return render_template("allmembers.html")

# This is for only certain LDAP group members
@app.route('/secret')
@authorization_required(allowed_groups=["secret", "top-secret"])  # does this exist?
@login_required
def secret():
    return render_template("secret.html")
```

I've looked at the "is_authenticated" method that goes with the Flask-Login "User" class, but that really seems to only get me to #1.  Is there a Flask-type method to proceed from the authenticated status to authorized status?

Or does Flask-Login's usefulness end after the authentication, and I need to figure out how to roll my own `@authorization_required` decorator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [flask-login docs](https://flask-login.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) specifically say it does not "Handle permissions beyond 'logged in or not.'"

So yes, you'll have to roll your own `@authorization_required` decorator.

Comment: So it does.  Too bad!  Time to learn how to write a decorator.